# Why 1 / [(x ^ 2 - 1) ^ 0.5 - 1] returns a ZeroDivisionError when x > 10^9?

Tags: python, divide-by-zero

The exercise I was doing said that there'd likely be an issue when trying to solve this expression for `10^9` (first exercise is to try `10^7`). I thought that it may have something to do with Python storing floats using 64 bits, but then the maximum signed integer is `9. ... x 10^18`, which is more than the `10^18` generated using the `x^2`, and the maximum and minimum (absolute values) for floats is usually of the order of magnitude of `10^308` and `10^-308`, if I'm not wrong. Also, I tried this using `np.float128()` and it works, but given the above limits I'm not sure why.

This doesn't work:

```py
x = 10 ** 9
f00 = 1 / ((x ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5 - x)
print(f00)
f01 = -(x ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5 - x
print(f01)
```

This works:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.float128(10 ** 9)
f00 = 1 / ((x ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5 - x)
print(f00)
f01 = np.float128(-(x ** 2 - 1) ** 0.5 - x)
print(f01)
```

Comment: You might not be anywhere near the limits of `float` range, but this is a *precision* issue, not a range issue.

Comment: Compare `float(10)**18` and `float(10)**18 - 1` and see how both evaluate to `1e+18`.

Answer (score -2):

I might be wrong, but as far as I know floats in python are stored in IEEE 754 double64 format. And have only 53 significant bits.

What this means.

When you try to store 10^9 as float you'll get 10^9 because it can be represented with 53 bits
But when you try to store 10^18, you need 60 bits to store the number which is greater than the capabilities of float to store whole number, that's why it will use exponenta, and you'll get 1e+18. And by substracting one you still get 1e+18.

That's why you get division by zero.

Comment: (10^9) ^ 2 is 10^18, which certainly won't.

Comment: log2(10^18) ~ 60 which is greater than 53, so the number won't be stored as is, but with use of exponenta. That's why 10^18 - 1 will remain 10^18 and that's why here we get division by zero.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason - but the explanation in your answer is wrong.